# Nightwatch/Selenium on Codeship

Tags: selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js, codeship

Has anyone been able to run Nightwatch tests on Codeship? If so, can you point me to documentation to help me set that up?

http://nightwatchjs.org/

Comment: I just went with the standard way, i.e during deployment in **second** pipeline I run my server on their virtual machine (in my case it's the npm task `npm run star`'). Then I wait around 30s to make sure server is up and running. After this pause, I run `./nightwatch.js` straight away and it works. Parallel spec runner seems to be problematic though.

Comment: I'm currently working with Codeship support to resolve this issue as well. Our set up is app code and tests in one service linked to a separate selenium service. Please let me know if anyone has a similar set up working!